# Handling Multiple Login Across The Browser Using Java

Tags: java, authentication

I have Created Dynamic Web Application.  There is USER table with column ENABLED to check if the user is already logged in or not:

- **ENABLED** = true --> logged in otherwise not
- if i logged in , i cannot login at the same time in another browser
- but if i logged in and close the browser, how can i handle further login ??

Comment: which frame work you are using ?

Answer (score 0):

Usually you specificy a session timeout, (i.e. 10 minutes), which means that session will be alive for ten minutes since last connection.

Maybe you can change the enabled column to a datetime column where you store the session expiration time, which should be updated in every request the user makes.

Any login request done before this expiration time should return an error, but login requests beyond this expiration time may succeed.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

You need not keep login ENABLED column for maintaining User Session unless u need a history of logins. The followings are the steps to achieve your goal.

1. User open login page and do login first time, keep login information in session map.
2. when they logout, clear session map or invalidate session (`httpSession.invalidate();
           userSessionMap.remove(userName);`)
3. If user already logged in and trying from other browser, do check session map and give them a warning "You are logged in already, do you want to logout from other location?"
4. for 3, If say yes, invalidate previous session and create new login
5. Maintain a session timeout
6. Without logout if they close browser, next login page will prompt the same warning message which mentioned in point no.3 since each time a new session will be created.

Thats it. Hope you can implement.

Comment: in the point 3, you cannot keep track of other login details.. as this is a new session..

Comment: @user1849556 you can keep existing logged in user by session map.